# How can I sythesize a sine audio wave with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio, synthesizer

I would like to try making a synth using JavaScript, but I can't find any basic examples on how to do so.

What I have figured out from research is that it [appears to be possible](http://js.do/blog/sound-waves-with-javascript/) and that you should [use a Canvas Pixel Array](http://www.bitsnbites.eu/?p=1) rather than normal ECMA arrays

I've also found info in [MDN Audio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio), and I have seen audio elements used for continuous playback by web radio players before, although I couldn't figure out how.

My goal is to make something which allows me to synthesize continuous sin waves and play them using my keyboard *without using pre-made samples*.

EDIT: One of the comments below pointed me in the right direction.  I'm currently working on a solution, but if you would like to post one as well, feel free.

Comment: Would [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Visualizations_with_Web_Audio_API) point you in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic example from which anyone should be able to figure out how to play sine waves with their keyboard:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //WARNING: VERY LOUD.  TURN DOWN YOUR SPEAKERS BEFORE TESTING

    // create web audio api context
    var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

    // create Oscillator node
    var oscillator = audioCtx.createOscillator();

    oscillator.type = 'sine';
    oscillator.frequency.value = 750; // value in hertz
    oscillator.connect(audioCtx.destination);
    oscillator.start();

    //uncomment for fun
    // setInterval(changeFreq, 100);

    //choose a random interval from a list of consonant ratios
    var intervals = [1.0, 0.5, 0.3333, 1.5, 1.3333, 2.0, 2.25]
    function changeFreq() {
        var intervalIndex = ~~(Math.random() * intervals.length);
        var noteFreq = oscillator.frequency.value * intervals[intervalIndex];

        //because this is random, make an effort to keep it in comfortable frequency range.
        if(noteFreq > 1600) 
            noteFreq *= 0.5;
        else if(noteFreq < 250) 
            noteFreq *= 2;


        oscillator.frequency.value = noteFreq;
    }
</script>

<body>
<button onclick="changeFreq()">Change Places!</button>
</body>
```